# Standard name for CZ gate conjugated by Hadamards?

Tags: quantum-gate, terminology-and-notation

Is there a standard name for a $CZ$ gate conjugated by $H \otimes H$ gates? See below for circuit

[image: HH CZ HH]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In stim this is called [the `XCX` gate](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/wiki/Stim-v1.8-Gate-Reference#XCX) (short for X-controlled X gate). Stim has A-controlled-B for all paulis A, B.

In Quirk you can make this gate by combining an X-axis control and an X gate. X-axis controls condition on the control being $|-\rangle$, instead of on the control being $|1\rangle$. Looks like this:

[image]

The concept of "controlling" can be generalized to work [on any pair of commuting operations](https://algassert.com/post/1706):

$$\text{Control}(A, B) = \text{Control}(B, A) = \exp(-i \ln(A) \ln(B) / \pi)$$

For example, you can check that:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{CNOT} &= \text{Control}(Z_0, X_1)  \\&= \text{Control}(Z \otimes I, I \otimes X)
\\
\\ \text{CZ} &= \text{Control}(Z_0, Z_1)
\\ \text{HadamardConjugatedCZ} &= \text{Control}(X_0, X_1)
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 3):

There’s no standard name, but if you wanted to draw it, you’d draw two $\oplus$ signs connected by a vertical line since the H will convert Z to X.